# How do I make an element fit the page fold exactly

Tags: jquery, html, css

Check out the demo on [Stripe's global page](https://stripe.com/global). How do they make it so that the blue area (the animation with the globe) fits the window width and height *exactly*.

**Note:** This only works on page load. Try resizing the browser window and hit refresh. You'll notice that the blue area fits the window height perfectly.

Comment: `width: 100%` + amazing JavaScript :)

Comment: @Jsve amazing indeed. It's magic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/hDcCb/)**</kbd>

```
<div></div>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $('div').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px', width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px' });

    // If you want it to update on window resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
      $('div').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px', width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px' });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```